# observeAsState not working for list, in jetpack compose

Tags: observer-pattern, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am trying to display a list of objects in a composable. for that i am having a viewmodel with below list variable

```
var allProviders: LiveData<MutableList<ServiceProvider>> = MutableLiveData(mutableListOf())
```

also, on view model init, i am calling an api to populate above list as:-

```
private fun getAllMerchantList() {
    getAllMerchants(object: RetrofitCallback {
        override fun onData(data: Any?) {
            //some logic here
            allProviders.value?.addAll(allProvidersLocal)
            Log.i("TAG", "ServiceProviders inside: ${allProviders.value?.size}")
        }

        override fun onFailed(ex: String?) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onFailed: ${ex.toString()}")
        }
    })
}
```

And, observing above, in composable, like:-

```
val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel = viewModel()
val allProviders by viewModel.allProviders.observeAsState()
```

but, above code is not working. Its always returning empty list in composable. But if i log through viewmodel function, i can see the data. How can i correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mutableStateListOf` instead of `LiveData` in Compose

`var allProviders by mutableStateListOf<ServiceProvider>()`

Now use it as a regular list object. It will trigger recompositions. Also, as far as possible use `MutableState` type objects in Compose since they are built for it, and vice versa.

Comment: I have seen many people facing this issue with `LiveData`, though I myself have never faced this. I still prefer `MutableState` over `LiveData`, anyhow

Comment: How to observe mutableState in Activity or Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
val mutableStateFlod: MutableStateFlow<MutableList<ServiceProvider>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
```

instead ov LiveData and all

```
collectAsState
```